# Why stopPropagation not preventing page navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, dom-events

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sun-znrd2

I have call stopPropagation at `a`'s child element `button` and `a` also didn't receive `click` event. But the page still navigated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `stopPropagation` which prevents event bubbling you need to use `event.preventDefault` to cancel default behaviour

```
 const onClickButton = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log("click Button");
      event.preventDefault();
      aElm.click();
    };
```

Comment: But the event seems like didn't reach `a` element. ️